# How to add checkbox input in each row of react-virtualized table?

Tags: reactjs, react-virtualized

I have a state that whenever the user scrolls in a specific part, the data is receieved from API and appendded to the end of this state. 
Because the data is big, 
I have used the table of react-virtualized, now I want to add check box input to each row of the table ,
But I’m not sure what is the best way to do it. What is the best solution?

Comment: check here,  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46551810/adding-dynamically-generated-checkboxes-to-react-table-and-capturing-row-data

Comment: You can check here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61318615/7994074.